# Distribute objects evenly focused on centre (Drawing graph)

Tags: c#, algorithm, math, graph, drawing

I have a problem that I suspected would be a lot simpler than it was. I'm trying to draw a graph under some specific guidelines. It's multiple columns and multiple rows, but not all columns have the same number of rows. I'd like the distance between nodes (on the vertical) to be the same for all nodes focused around the centre, to create a graph something like the following:

```
o     o
   o
o     o   
   o
o     o
```

(The middle column only has two nodes, but they are the same distance from each other as in the three node columns.)
I could probably work this out by just calculating the distance based on the column with the most nodes, then working from the centre (-y for the nodes above the centre point +y for those below) but it doesn't seem like the most elegant solution.

Comment: This is actually a personal project, not for homework or assignment or work or anything like that. And I said the best solution I could come up with at the end, but I don't like it. It feels cheap and inelegant.

Comment: StackOverflow is a platform to help eachother on concrete coding problems not for providing complete solutions.

Comment: Then give him some tips and not complete solutions instead of only criticizing.

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches:

1. From the center point, "draw" a circle and place the points at specific angles on it's border. Now move the center in the direction where you want to have and place points again. Overlaps can be removed.
2. Draw the first set of points where where, e. g. the distance between x and y is equal. Then move right below with x/2 and y/2 (or similar) and draw the next elements.

I hope these rather coarse suggestions are not to unclear ;)